# How to get High resolution wallpaper generated by mbousq for 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) wallpaper competition?

Tags: 22.04, desktop-background

Sometimes Contacting people is basically impossible, likely by design.
I really love the wallpapers submitted here
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-22-04-wallpaper-competition/26388/95
And Here
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-22-04-wallpaper-competition/26388/97
How does one contact u/mbousq / @mbousq, in order to get higher resolution versions ? i.e. 4k and ultrawide formats.

Or at least how were these wallpapers made ?

Shouting this out into the internet and hoping the void answers back :)

Comment: Have you tried sending a PM on the Ubuntu Community Hub?  The creator may also be [Mathieu on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~mbousq) which will allow you to send an email  (*this may or may not be the same person, but a polite enquiry may get a result*)

Comment: Those look quite vector-like, so we should be able to process them ourselves. I thought of using Inkscape's Multicolor colors+smooth to "trace bitmap". The result for image 97 was fine but image 95 was horrible. Then I tried stable diffusion webui and the results were amazing! Everything was sharp and there were no edge artifacts from inkscape. I found the best upscaler for these images was "R-ESRGAN 4x+ Anime6B", and I could even go to 8k. Too bad I'm not allowed to post the output, so you would need to run it yourself or find an instance.